# Uncaught insert function argument is not a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

The console is showing errors on lines 5 and 8. The error is "Uncaught insert function argument is not a string." Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
$(function() {
var animation = false;
function typed(term, message, delay, finish) {
    animation = true;
    var da = 0;
    term.set_prompt('');
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        term.insert(message[da++]);
        if(da > message.length) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            setTimeout(function() {
                term.set_command('')
                term.set_prompt(message + ' ');
                animation = false;
                finish && finish();
            }, delay);
        }
    }, delay);
}
$('#fyeah').terminal(function(cmd, term) {
    var finish = false;
}, {
    name: 'test',
    greetings: null,
    onInit: function(term) {
        var msg = "testing";
        typed(term, msg, 150, function() {
            finish = true;
        });
    },
    keydown: function(e) {
        if (animation) {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

});

Comment: well this is not possible to answer with the code you have provided. We would need to know what you are passing in message as when it gets passed to the typed function. my initial thought is that it's just not formatted as a string correctly.

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Comment: @Bergi looks like [this one](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/)

Comment: One error on two lines? How did you get that?

Comment: Yep @Pointy is right! it's [that one](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/)

Comment: @Jordan have you tried adding a `console.log()` before the call to the "insert" function to see what "message" and "da" are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three cases when `message[da++]` "*is not a string*":

- `message` is the empty string
- (old) IE do not support bracket notation for getting single characters of strings, better use the `.charAt()` method
- in the last iteration of your loop, `da == message.length` - it ends only when `da` is already greater than the length. Yet, the indices are zero-based and run from `0` to `length-1`.

To fix it, use

```
// init
var da = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (da < message.length) {
        term.insert(message.charAt(da++)); // maybe better move the incrementing
                                           // out, to the end of the loop
    } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
        // teardown / callback
    }
}, delay);
```